# Cart Empty only for guest user in Drupal 7.21

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am facing an issue. My cart is showing empty for not logged in customer only. If I logged in then its working perfect. As I can check, after clicking on add to cart button, entries on database are occur in field_data_commerce_line_items and field_data_commerce_order_total as well. I am new to Drupal and I have not developed this website as well. Please help.

Website: https://www.floraharrison.com/

Comment: With these scarce information, nobody will be able to help you. My first guess would be a permission problem, check at `Users > Permissions` if the anonymous user is allowed to add items to and view the shopping bag.

Comment: You are using Drupal Commerce, right?

Comment: I also have the same problem. Any solution for that?